# How do you copy data within a specific set of rows in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from one sheet (sheet1) to another (sheet2) but I need the data to be placed in the next empty cell within a defined set of rows. For example;

I want to copy data into the next available cell within cells A10 and A30 but cells A1 through A9 are blank

I know that this will copy code in the next available cell until A31 but I don't want it to include A1 through A9

```
.Range("A30").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
```

Can anyone help please???

Comment: You have not described what should happen if there are no blank cells in A10:a30. Insert a row? Overwrite A10 or A30 or some other random row?

Comment: Those rows should be blank because there's a reset button, that will clear those cells if they're not blank. I need it to add data to next available cell within those rows (A10:A30)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
.Range("A" & WorksheetFunction.Max(10, .Range("A30").End(xlUp).Row)).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
```

Comment: I gave you the statement to be inserted in the same "environment" as the one in your question, i.e. with a leading "dot" which means you are in a "With ... End With" block. If it's not like that then show all relevant code where to insert that single statement in

Comment: @Amena56, did you get through it?